# How to create dynamic pdf with multiple rows?

Tags: php, pdf, thinkphp

I created one pdf from PHP.

but the loop rows printed like merging

```
    foreach($details as $b => $k)
    {
        $pdf->cell(70,80,$k['name'],20);
        $pdf->cell(70,80,$k['order_id'],20);
        $pdf->cell(70,80,$k['money'],20);
        $pdf->SetXY(5,125);
    }
```

[image]

The second row and third fourth are merged

Comment: Are you using fpdf?

Comment: you need to have new lines `$pdf->ln()` at the end of the 1st row

Comment: it goes next page @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: yes i am using FPDF @Timmetje

Comment: @JoygiveKalai what you mean it goes next page?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile ,  each row printed on seperate page in pdf viewer but i want in next line only.

Comment: use MultiCell  for more information check http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: i cant understand your point @WillParky93

Comment: I made that comment before looking at the parameters for fpdf, ignore it.